# Not including a 'first page' and 'last page' button in a data table

Tags: data-tables, material-design

So, in general my experience is that the Material Design spec by Google has been extremely well thought out, which doesn't mean I blindly follow it, but at least I think twice about every decision they do make. So I noticed that in their Data Table spec they do not include buttons to go the first and last page. As 17 out of the first 20 paginated data tables on Google Images *do* include those buttons I can't simply dismiss this as 'oh hey, they forgot', so, are there any good reasons to not include those buttons explicitly?

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: There isn't a direct specification for pagination in their [design documents](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html). I think you infer something from the screenshot which you shouldn't. Last page links may or may not be useful for users depending on the data presented. My guess is that for exactly such reason there is no direct reference to this issue.

Comment: @Izhaki Their screenshots are kinda part of the spec~

Answer (score 2):

I think a short answer is ***it depends***...

I see the following pros in using these links:

- A visitor is able to quickly navigate back to the beginning of collection with a single click (assuming they are deep in their browsing session and page #1 is no longer visible)
- If a collection is sorted "price low to high" but the opposite sorting is not given. There might be a case where a viewer is interested to look at most expensive items.
- A visitor somehow landed on a page "N" of the results list via an organic search and after digesting the information they want to go to the first page

**However ...**

Most viewers prefer to look at content chronologically. If all necessary filtering and sorting options are provided, then I don't see a need to display those buttons. There are also different pagination design patterns that could be used to cover any gaps.

Example:
[image: Pagination Example]

Answer (score 0):

One good reason is if you only have a few pages of results.

Then it is better to link to each individual page, rather than first, previous, next, last.

e.g.

1   **2**   3   4   5   6